# Python Json dumps not printing values

Tags: json, python-2.7

I am trying out a simple program

```
import json

class unified_response():
trinitiversion="3"
preprocess = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
 ur = unified_response()
 preprocessValDict = dict()
 preprocessValDict["input"] = "some string"
 preprocessValDict["correct"] = " correct some string"
 ur.preprocess.append(preprocessValDict)

 s = json.dumps(unified_response.__dict__)
 print s
 s = json.dumps(ur.__dict__)
 print s
```

First print statement prints

```
{"preprocess": [{"input": "some string", "correct": " correct some string"}], "trinitiversion": "3", "__module__": "__main__", "__doc__": null}
```

Second print statement prints

```
{}
```

Why is the second object not printing any values?

Answer (score 0):

This is not related at all to the `json` module.

`ur.__dict__` is an empty dictionary since only instance attributes are saved in the instance.

The `unified_response` class only has class attributes hence `ur.__dict__` is an empty dict which `json.dumps` transforms to an empty string.

Compare the outputs of `print unified_response.__dict__` and `print ur.__dict__`.

As a side note:

`ur.preprocess.append(preprocessValDict)`

Accessing (and especially modifying) class attributes through an instance is considered a bad practice as it can lead to hard-to-find bugs.